# JMeter sends request without Auth Header than retries with Auth Header

Tags: jmeter

On my JMeter script I am using the HTTP Authorization Manager, I observed that JMeter sends requests without Auth-Header and than retry with Auth-Header and successful. Is any settings to avoid this. Please let me know.

```
Jmeter sends Request1 with out Auth-Header - tcpdump shows 401 but not on Jmeter logs
Jmeter sends Request1 with Auth-Header - tcpdump and Jmeter logs shows 200 OK
```

Answer (score 1):

My expectation is that if you upgrade to [JMeter 3.2](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-jmeter-32) you should not see this issue anymore as according to the [HTTP Authorization Manager documentation](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager):

> The HttpComponents (HC 4.5.X) implementation defaults to pre-emptive since 3.2 and the header will be shown

If for some reason you are not in position to upgrade to JMeter 3.2 or later (although it is [highly recommended to use the most recent JMeter version](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version)) you can add the next line to *user.properties* file

```
httpclient4.auth.preemptive=true
```

See [Preemptive Authentication](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/authentication.html#Preemptive_Authentication) stanza for more details.

Make sure you set "Implementation" of your HTTP Request sampler(s) to `HttpClient4`, the best way to set it is using [HTTP Request Defaults](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults) and restart JMeter to pick the property up. Once done JMeter should send credentials even if it didn't receive unauthorized response. See [Configuring JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter) chapter for more information.

Comment: This is working fine in Jmeter 3.2 version. Thank You